# Efficient way to calculate metrics from nested JSON, via python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

What is the most efficient way to calculate metrics from nested JSON, via python?

Given the JSON blob below, how can I calculate the user (ie profileId) with the most events - without using the pandas library and not having multiple nested for loops? I am having trouble writing the code the would not rely on  O(N2).

```
{
   "kind":"admin#reports#activities",
   "etag":"\"5g8\"",
   "nextPageToken":"A:1651795128914034:-4002873813067783265:151219070090:C02f6wppb",
   "items":[
      {
         "kind":"admin#reports#activity",
         "id":{
            "time":"2022-05-05T23:59:39.421Z",
            "uniqueQualifier":"5526793068617678141",
            "applicationName":"token",
            "customerId":"cds"
         },
         "etag":"\"jkYcURYoi8\"",
         "actor":{
            "email":"blah@blah.net",
            "profileId":"1323"
         },
         "ipAddress":"107.178.193.87",
         "events":[
            {
               "type":"auth",
               "name":"activity",
               "parameters":[
                  {
                     "name":"api_name",
                     "value":"admin"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"method_name",
                     "value":"directory.users.list"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"client_id",
                     "value":"722230783769-dsta4bi9fkom72qcu0t34aj3qpcoqloq.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"num_response_bytes",
                     "intValue":"7158"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"product_bucket",
                     "value":"GSUITE_ADMIN"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"app_name",
                     "value":"Untitled project"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"client_type",
                     "value":"WEB"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "kind":"admin#reports#activity",
         "id":{
            "time":"2022-05-05T23:58:48.914Z",
            "uniqueQualifier":"-4002873813067783265",
            "applicationName":"token",
            "customerId":"df"
         },
         "etag":"\"5T53xK7dpLei95RNoKZd9uz5Xb8LJpBJb72fi2HaNYM/9DTdB8t7uixvUbjo4LUEg53_gf0\"",
         "actor":{
            "email":"blah.blah@bebe.net",
            "profileId":"1324"
         },
         "ipAddress":"54.80.168.30",
         "events":[
            {
               "type":"auth",
               "name":"activity",
               "parameters":[
                  {
                     "name":"api_name",
                     "value":"gmail"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"method_name",
                     "value":"gmail.users.messages.list"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"client_id",
                     "value":"927538837578.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"num_response_bytes",
                     "intValue":"2"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"product_bucket",
                     "value":"GMAIL"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"app_name",
                     "value":"Zapier"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"client_type",
                     "value":"WEB"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: "I know i can do it in pandas" - where is the relevant code?

Comment: I do not have it yet because I am trying to decide what approach to take, so that is why I posted here. Would having it help you help me?

Comment: first write any code and later try to optimize it.

Answer (score -1):

This would be a good place to start:

```
data = # your dict.
ids = [x['actor']['profileId'] for x in data['items']]
print(ids)
```

Output:

```
['1323', '1324']
```